# PDF Viewer hosting forms hugging control after closing

Tags: c#, winforms, pdfviewer, axacropdf

A bunch of my C# and VB programs utilize `PDFViewer` control and `AxAcroPDFlib`. It's been serving me well for years but recently, after installing Adobe Reader DC, all applications using `PDFViewer` started to have problems.

`PDFViewer` controls open PDF documents really fast, instantly. However, when I go to close the form hosting `PDFViewer` control with open PDF document, the form takes anywhere between 5-10 seconds to return control to other form in the same program. Other forms just remain disabled, with hourglass mouse pointer for an extended time. Is there new `AxAcroPDFlib` that should be used with Reader DC?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to track down the issue to the actual `PDFViewer` control. When Adobe Reader DC is installed, and if `PDFViewer` control has `Focus`, the form will have trouble closing. I added `FormClosing` event handler and added some code to assign `Focus` to a control other than `PDFViewer` and then I also disposed of `PDFViewer` instance. Worked like a charm.